# preg_replace only display numbers and dashes

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
Height (cm): 200 - 250 (cm)
```

I only want to display numbers and dashes so the remaining string will be:

```
200 - 250
```

Here is my attempt but how do i include the dash?

```
 $item_data = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $item_data);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just add the dash and a space to it. Also don't forget to trim() the string to get rid of the spaces at the start and the end of the value.

```
$str = "Height (cm): 200 - 250 (cm)";
echo $item_data = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9 -]/", '', $str));
```

output:

```
200 - 250
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `-` only. Add it to the pattern. Try with -

```
$item_data = preg_replace("/[^0-9 \-]/", '', $item_data);
```

Comment: With this you are losing the spaces in between the numbers! And as it looks in OP's question I think he wants to keep them